# How can I use multiple Check functions in the [Registry] section?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Sample:

```
Root: "HKLM64"; Subkey: "Software\Community Talks\Public Talks\Preferences"; \
  ValueType: dword; ValueName: "ReuseCong"; ValueData: "{code:ReuseCongregation}"; \
  Flags: uninsdeletevalue; Check: IsNewInstall IsWin64
Root: "HKLM64"; Subkey: "Software\Community Talks\Public Talks\Preferences"; \
  ValueType: dword; ValueName: "Duplicate"; ValueData: "{code:Duplicate}"; \
  Flags: uninsdeletevalue; Check: IsNewInstall IsWin64
Root: "HKLM64"; Subkey: "Software\Community Talks\Public Talks\Preferences"; \
  ValueType: dword; ValueName: "Language"; ValueData: "{code:DatabaseLanguage}"; \
  Flags: uninsdeletevalue; Check: IsNewInstall IsWin64
```

Will not compile:

> Error on line 406 in `setup.iss`: Directive or parameter `"Check"` expression error: Invalid token `'IsWin64'` found.

---

I can't change the `IsNewInstall` function:

```pascal
// Returns True if we are performing a new install
function IsNewInstall(): Boolean;
begin
  // Make sure IsUpgrading has already beed called.
  result := not bIsUpgrading;
end;
```

But I include it if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) supports simple boolean operators like `or` or `and`. Examples are given at the end of [Components and Tasks Parameters documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams).

You want `and` here, I assume:

```
Check: IsNewInstall and IsWin64
```

---

Alternatively, particularly if the expression gets too complicated or when it is used frequently, you can factor it out to a separate function:

```pascal
function IsNewInstallOnWin64: Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsNewInstall and IsWin64;
end;
```